# previous function input parameter correct storing

Tags: clojure

I started to learn clojure so pardon for noob question 
I try to implement following function

pseudo code:

```
function(x y) {
  if (x != oldX)
    dosomething(y);
  oldX = x;
}
```

`oldX` is global variable

How can i properly do this the clojure way?

I wrote something this but is this correct way or not?

```
(defn rec [x y]  
  (if (not= x oldX)
    (println "y"))
  (def oldX x))
```

Comment: And when you tried to implement it, what happened?

Comment: does this mean that i creat always new oldX but what happens to the older one?

Comment: Yes, you create a new variable with the same name, but only in the scope of your function. The old one lives with the old value in the scope, where you defined it. Clojure variables are immutable.

Comment: if i do this at the top level of a repl: `(def old-x 2)` and evaluate `old-x`, i get `=> 2`.  
if i then `(def rec [x y] (if (not= x old-x) (println "y")) (def old-x x))`, evaluate `(rec 3 4)` and then `old-x` i get `=> 3` - why is that?

Comment: `def` defines new variables in the namespace. Therefore another `def` creates a new variable on the top level.

Comment: In the comments below @user1571406 made a small example, where this case is explained. He posted this link: https://ideone.com/I6rHbT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defs` should only be top level. `(def oldX (atom nil))` and `(reset! oldX x)` is more correct.

Comment: Ok i thoght that clojure is inmutable

Answer (score 3):

Clojure is a functional programming language. This is a different paradigm than it is used in other popular programming languages like Python. It appears that you are not thinking functional ;-)

The Clojure-way would be not to use a variable for this case. Just solve it with functions or, if it is really necessary, use `atoms` or `ref`s, depending on what you need.

An `atom` or a `ref` can be modified within a function to store the old result - this may be the solution you are looking for.

But for most cases there exists a simpler solution without the need for a variable like `oldX` - and this is were the benefits of a functional language come into place.

**Your Code**

```
(defn rec [x y]  
  (if (not= x oldX)
    (println "y"))
  (def oldX x))
```

As @cgrand already said, `def` should only be used on the first level.

You use `if`, but you define only the `true` case. If you check only, if a certain statement is true, then you can use `when`.

The last line defines a new `oldX` in the scope of the function `rec`. This is a *new* variable, not the old one with a new value, in the active namespace (thanks to @user1571406).

Comment: `def` modifies the active *namespace* (i.e. `*ns*`). That usually propagates the change to its enclosing scope if it has one because it is in the same namespace, but it is a mutation of state which is visible from anywhere. See for instance this ideone snippet: http://ideone.com/I6rHbT

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this. I've tried to keep your var names as your originals, so it's easier to see the difference.

1. Use an `atom` to store `oldX`
2. Use a `compare-and-set!` to determine whether you've changed the atom
3. If you've changed the atom, call your `(dosomething y)`

*Note:* This is kind of like a `swap!`, except `swap!` returns the value swapped in, not whether or not your call to `swap!` changed the value, so it's less useful here.

Something like this:

```
(defn dosomething [y] 
  ;; does something, presumably with y...
  )

(defonce x-atom (atom nil))

(defn swap-x
  "swaps x-atom for new x, calls (dosomething ...) with y if successful"
  [x y]
  (let [oldX @x-atom] ; get the cur value of x
    (when (not= oldX x)
      (when (compare-and-set! x-atom oldX x)
        (dosomething y))
```

If the `compare-and-set!` fails, then it means some other thread has modified the atom since you got its value. If you need to handle that case, the answer is a little different. You could either use a `swap!` or a `loop+recur`. If you're unfamiliar, a `swap!` is sort of like a `compare-and-set!` that recurs on failure.